# onInstanceState and Back Button

Tags: android, android-activity, back, android-lifecycle

The Android documentation regarding the recreation of an activity states:

*When your activity is destroyed because the user presses Back or the activity finishes itself, the system's concept of that Activity instance is gone forever because the behavior indicates the activity is no longer needed. However, if the system destroys the activity due to system constraints (rather than normal app behavior), then although the actual Activity instance is gone, the system remembers that it existed such that if the user navigates back to it, the system creates a new instance of the activity using a set of saved data that describes the state of the activity when it was destroyed.*

To clarify: does this mean that `onSavedInstanceState` becomes `null` when the user presses the back button?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it seems yes... Android follows many bad design decisions :(